# How do i compare a Number to a Payload action with redux & typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

The use effect is to take in total data return, divide by 3 and dispatch into `totalPagesInDB` so I can retrieve the value and use it to disable the Next button in the `Pagination` component. I get this error

This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'number' and 'ActionCreatorWithPayload<number, "pagination/totalPagesInDB">' have no overlap.ts(2367)
(alias) const totalPagesInDB: ActionCreatorWithPayload<number, "pagination/totalPagesInDB">
import totalPagesInDB

on this line `disabled={currentPage === totalPagesInDB}`

Full code

```js
//paginationSlice.ts
"use client";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RootState } from "@/app/GlobalRedux/store";

interface PageState {
  value: number;
}

const initialState: PageState = {
  value: 1,
} as PageState;

export const paginationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "pagination",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    next: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    prev: (state) => {
      if (state.value > 1) state.value -= 1;
    },
    totalPagesInDB: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { next, prev, totalPagesInDB } = paginationSlice.actions;

export const paginationSearch = (state: RootState) => state.pagination.value;

export default paginationSlice.reducer;
```

```js
//HomeMainBody.tsx
"use client";

import ...

export default function HomeMainBody() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const currentPage = useAppSelector(paginationSearch);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await getAllVehicles(currentPage);
      dispatch(totalPagesInDB(Math.ceil(data.count / 3)));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [currentPage]);

  return (
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// Pagination.tsx
export default function Pagination() {
  const currentPage = useAppSelector(paginationSearch);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const handleNextPage = () => {
    dispatch(next());
  };

  const handlePreviousPage = () => {
    dispatch(prev());
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center my-5 align-items-center gap-3 ">
      <button
        onClick={handlePreviousPage}
        className="btn btn-outline-dark"
        disabled={currentPage === 1}
      >
        Back
      </button>
      <div>Page {} of</div>
      <button
        onClick={handleNextPage}
        className="btn btn-outline-dark"
        disabled={currentPage === totalPagesInDB}
      >
        Next{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Next button in this component contains the disabled attribute which has the error